# User synced from AD with wrong Name

Tags: profile-sync, ad

I'm on a Sharepoint 2013 On Premise farm and I have a problem with one user. It gets synced with the wrong name and email (from another user - both are AD Users, both have different SIDs and they're not linked in any way as far as I can see. I'm not an AD guru, though)

What I've tried so far:

Checked for the user profile synchronization Service in central admin- The Service is running

Run sync with powershell using `Set-SPUser -Web "https://mysites.domain.cc" -SyncFromAD` and `Set-SPUser -Web "https://sharepoint.domain.cc" -SyncFromAD` - nothing changed

Full Sync with `STSADM -o sync -ignoreisactive 1` - nothing changed

Deleting User from "All People" in both web applications - sharepoint and mysites.

Deleting User via Powershell with `Remove-SPUser "i:03.w|DOMAIN\USER" -web "https://sharepoint.domain.cc"` and `Remove-SPUser "i:03.w|DOMAIN\USER" -web "https://mysites.domain.cc"` and deleting site collection from mysites web application in central administration.

When I then logon to sharepoint with the user again, it first shows the correct name top right, but when I go to "About Me" it links to the wrong information (wrong name, wrong e-mail, wrong phone) and after a few minutes it shows the wrong name top right again. Although when I send an e-mail from sharepoint it sends to the correct e-mail address.

There are no known problems with other users, but I don't want to recreate the AD user, because of exchange and file server permissions.

Comment: After going to About Me, if you go back to sharepoint.domain.cc, do you see correct user name / wrong one? Also is this issue getting reproduced on different client machines / browsers?

Comment: After going back the name changes to the wrong one on sharepoint.domain.cc, too. It's appearing on the users client on IE and chrome as well as on mine when opening IE or chrome as different user.